# Bumbling around plotting two sets of seasonal data on the same chart

Tags: altair

I have series of monthly inventory data since 2017.
I have a series of inventory_forecasts since Dec2018

I am trying to plot the inventory data on a monthly-seasonal basis,  and then overlay the inventory_forecasts of Jan2019 through Dec2019.

The dataframe looks like:

[image]

The first way I tried to make the chart does show all the data I want, but I'm unable to control the color of the `inventory_zj` line.  Its color seems to be dominated by the `color=year(date):N` of the `alt.Chart` I configured.  It is ignoring the `color='green'` I pass to the `mark_line()`

```
base = alt.Chart(inv.loc['2000':].reset_index(), title=f"usa total inventory").mark_line().encode(
    x='month',
    y="inventory",
    color="year(date):N"
)

#this ignores my 'green' color instruction, and marks it the same light blue 2019 color
joe = base.mark_line(color='green').encode(
    alt.Y('inventory_zj', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False), )
)

base+joe
```

[image]

I tried to use a layering system,  but it's not working at all -- I cannot get it to display the "joe" layer

```
base = alt.Chart(inv.loc['2000':].reset_index(), title=f"usa total inventory").encode(
    x='month(date)'
)

doe = base.mark_line().encode(
    alt.Y('inventory', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False), ),
    color="year(date):N"
)


joe = base.mark_line(color="green").encode(
    alt.Y('inventory_zj', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False), ),
)



#looks identical to the first example
alt.layer(
    doe, joe
).resolve_scale(
    y='shared'
).configure_axisLeft(labelColor='black').configure_axisRight(labelColor='green',titleColor='green')

#independent shows a second y-axis (which is different from the left y-axis) but no line
alt.layer(
    doe, joe
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
).configure_axisLeft(labelColor='black').configure_axisRight(labelColor='green',titleColor='green')
```

[image]

I feel like i must be trying to assemble this chart in a fundamentally wrong way.  I should be able to share teh same left y-axis,  have the historic data colored by its year, and have a unique color for the 2019-forecasted data.  But I seem to be making a mess of it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Customizing Visualizations](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#global-config-vs-local-config-vs-encoding) docs, there are multiple ways to specify things like line color, with a well-defined hierarchy: encodings override mark properties, which override top-level configurations.

In your chart, you write `base.mark_point(color='green')`, where `base` contains a color encoding which overrides the mark property. If you don't derive the layer from base (so that it does not have a color encoding), then the line will be green as you hoped. Something like this:

```
base = alt.Chart(inv.loc['2000':].reset_index(), title=f"usa total inventory")

inventory = base.mark_line().encode(
    x='month',
    y="inventory",
    color="year(date):N"
)

joe = base.mark_line(color='green').encode(
    x='month',
    y=alt.Y('inventory_zj', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False))
)

inventory + joe
```