# Passing a .loc[date] slice into altair chart has odd results depending on slice date

Tags: pandas, altair

Was [struggling with plotting a few layers of a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661289/bumbling-around-plotting-two-sets-of-seasonal-data-on-the-same-chart) before I realized the layer specification wasn't the problem, but that somehow the slice I pass the  chart is acting (to me) oddly.  If it's not broken,  then I must misunderstand how things should work.

Attaching a concrete example to demonstrate how this works and how I think it shouldn't be working like this.

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IndexSlice

history_index = pd.date_range(start="31jan2016", end="30jun2019", freq="M")
forecast_index = pd.date_range(start="31jan2019", end="31dec2019", freq="M")

history_df = pd.DataFrame([z for z in range(len(history_index))], index=history_index,columns = ['history'])
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame([z for z in range(len(forecast_index))], index=forecast_index, columns = ['forecast'])

df = history_df.join(forecast_df, how="outer")
df.index.name = "date"
```

The first example works:

```
#without making it a seasonal chart,  this works
non_seasonal  = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20170701':],:].reset_index(), title=f"non seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='date',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
non_seasonal
```

[image]

But when I start turning these into seasonal charts, by making the X-axis month, problems emerge.

My first slice works, I'm just slicing all the existing `forecast` data, which begins in Jan2019.

```
#works ok: shows all the data since 1jan2019
seasonal1 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20190101':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
seasonal1
```

[image]

But when I start slicing from earlier dates (before 'forecast' has any data),  I have trouble.

```
#fails:  shows no data
seasonal2 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180101':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
seasonal2
```

[image]

I can make the data appear if I add a color encoding, but this isn't a solution that will work for me ultimately.

```
#works if I add a color-encoding
seasonal3 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180101':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    color="year(date):N"
    )
seasonal3
```

[image]

Things start becoming really weird at this point.  If I start my slice anywhere in 2018,  the "start" of the slice seems to act as the "end" of the slice instead....

```
#fails bizarrely -- the 20180701 slice appears to be the END of the slice, not the start
seasonal4 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180701':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
seasonal4
```

[image]

again, it works if i give it a color encoding

```
#again, it works if I add a color encoding.
seasonal5 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180701':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        color="year(date):N"
    )
seasonal5
```

[image]

So the obvious quick-get-around is to add a color-encoding.  But this won't work for me, as I'm trying to layer multiple sets of data on this chart (the historic data colored by year) and the forecast data hard-coded to red.

=============================================

Based on Jake's answer below, I reach the final product I wanted:

```
forecast = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180101':],'forecast'].reset_index().dropna(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line(color="green").encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )

history = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20170101':],'history'].reset_index().dropna(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'history', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        color="year(date):O"
    )

forecast+history
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `mark_line()` to `mark_point()`, you'll see that the data is actually there, but it's not showing in the line chart. Why? Because a line is only drawn between adjacent non-null points.

Look at the output of `df.loc[idx['20180101':],:]`: you'll see that it contains many rows with mostly NaN values. When you extract the month from the index, these NaN values are interspersed among the defined values with matching months, which creates breaks in the line: in some cases, there are so many breaks that there are no longer any adjacent non-null points to connect, and so no line is drawn.

Incidentally, this is why adding the color encoding improves the situation: it means that the null data from previous years is no longer included in the same group as the defined data, and so adjacent points are non-null and a line can be drawn.

To fix this, I'd suggest being more careful about how you are slicing your data, and/or filter the NaN values of the slices you're creating. For example, in your `seasonal2` chart, you might do this:

```
df_sliced = df.loc[idx['20180101':],:].dropna().reset_index()
seasonal2 = alt.Chart(df_sliced, title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='month(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
seasonal2
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `yearmonth` rather than `month` when extracting the dates, which prevents the undefined data from being interspersed with defined data:

```
seasonal2 = alt.Chart(df.loc[idx['20180101':],:].reset_index(), title=f"seasonal plot").mark_line().encode(
        x='yearmonth(date)',
        y=alt.Y(f'forecast', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
seasonal2
```

[image]

The other examples can be fixed in a similar manner.

Comment: "When you extract the month from the index, these NaN values are interspersed among the defined values with matching months, "   I guess this means a series being pass to chart might look like: ...4/18(None), 4/19(483), 5/18(None), 5/19(492), 6/18 (None), 6/19 (499)... which has no adjacent non-nulls.   Ok, makes sense to me now... Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question to show how your answer solves the overall problem.  Also I didn't appreciate that I could layer charts whose data are sourced from different dataframes or dataframe slices...